# Django ORM: Given A n:1 B, how do I get all As that have no B with B.foo=VALUE attached to them?

Tags: python, django

I have the following setup:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    foo = models.TextField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='bs')
```

And I want to filter for every A that doesn't have a relationship with a B that has foo set to SOME_VALUE.

I tried

```
A.objects.exclude(bs__foo=SOME_VALUE)
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Use related_query_name param but not related_name

Comment: How does that help? It only gives me the possibility to have the attribute on A and the way I address the B relation in queries be different?

Comment: I should have written more than "doesn't work" obviously. It's not like the query fails, it just doesn't return what I want it to return. I don't in fact understand what exactly it does, just that it doesn't filter the way I described I want.

Comment: "I should have written more than "doesn't work" obviously" : yes obviously. Actually your query should do exactly what you ask for: filter out all A instances having a related B instance with foo==SOME_VALUE. Chances are the SOME_VALUE you want to exclude is not _EXACTLY_ the one you stored...